# Removing last newline in csv.writerow

Tags: python

I'm writing output to a CSV using csv.writerow(), and it works fine except at the end there's a newline character that shows that I have 11 rows when I open the CSV. Is there a nice way to get rid of that?

```
with open(outputPath, 'w', newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        for x in range(0,10):
            writer.writerow([str(x), "10"])
```

EDIT: changed wording of the question

Comment: How do you know there's an empty row? Are there actually two newlines in a row at the end? Because ending in a single newline is normal/correct.

Comment: you might be right, it ends in a single newline. But the output does have 11 lines when I open it, is there a way I can get rid of that last newline?

Comment: Aside from backing up a byte (or whatever the encoding's idea of a newline occupies) with `seek` on the underlying file and calling `truncate` on it, no. This sounds like an issue with whatever editor you're opening it with; it shouldn't treat a single terminal newline as an extra row (POSIX text file standards actually *require* the final line end in a newline; it's not technically a text file without it, and any sane editor should recognize that a single terminal newline followed by nothing is the end of that line, not indicating another line follows it).

Comment: can you write the first 9 lines with your original `csv.writer` and then write the 10th line with a `csv.writer` where you set the `lineterminator` option to ""

Comment: @ShadowRanger beat me to it, but yes, that newline should be expected.